# Could not find schema information for the element 'shape'

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

I have a custom xml for the custom EditText layout. But I always have a messages like this:

[image]

and here is my code for the custom EditText Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

       android:thickness="0dp"

       android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="3dp"

           android:color="#4799E8"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <gradient

     android:startColor="#C8C8C8"

     android:endColor="#FFFFFF"

     android:type="linear"

     android:angle="270"/>
  </shape>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:thickness="0dp"
   android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke android:width="3dp"
       android:color="#4799E8"/>
<corners android:radius="5dp" />

<gradient
 android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
 android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
 android:type="linear"
 android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

remove the set tag in your code .

**Note**

You should add shape xml code in the `drawable` directory .

**Edit**

Delete the `inputText.xml` in project view and re-run as android application .

And re_new the `inputText.xml` .

Comment: still the same. This is the screen shot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_NWI7w3lXlfSW0wM1BXX3hqZ1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Kmmp did you added the xml into drawable directory?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT yes

Comment: @Kmmp well, I can't get the error when I drop the `inputText.xml` into drawable folder, please make sure you remove the previous xml file from other folder and try rebuild the solution.